# Yet another question on mobile compatible website

Tags: iphone, android, windows-mobile, symbian

Greetings to all of you!

I would like to know how do i need to design a web compatible website for iPhone /Android/Symbion/Windows mobile ( All of the mobile platform )

Actually what i need to know is Do i have to design every single page for every mobile platform?( because i hope every mobile screen size gets varied! )

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/  or  http://www.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2011/02/16/mobile-sites-vs-media-queries/) at sitepoint.com discusses the relative merits of designing separate mobile sites as opposed to using CSS media queries to change your stylesheet based on screen size.

Generally speaking, single-column layouts whith flexible widths is the way to go - let the mobile browser do the resizing/flow control.